# Best way to make a custom select in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html-select

I'm using the MEAN stack (Angular 6) and I'm still looking for the best way to build a custom and reusable `<select>` form control which uses an Array of strings returned from the BE to generate all `<option>` tags. Let's say for example we have 3 materials `wood`, `metal` and `plastic` and the returned Array can be one of the following (stored in the `materials` variable):

```
(in my example.component.ts)

form = new FormGroup({
  'material' = new FormControl('')
});

get material() {return this.form.get('material');}

materials = [
  {
    key: "mat_wood",
    value: "Wood"
  },
  {
    key: "mat_metal",
    value: "Metal"
  },
  {
    key: "mat_plastic",
    value: "Plastic"
  }
]
```

or

```
(in my example.component.ts)

form = new FormGroup({
  'material' = new FormControl('')
});

get material() {return this.form.get('material');}

materials = [
  {"mat_wood": "Wood"},
  {"mat_metal": "Metal"},
  {"mat_plastic": "Plastic"}
]
```

and we have this HTML structure:

```
(in my example.component.html)

<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="select-wrap">
    <span class="select-value">{{}}</span>

    <select formControlName="material">
      <option *ngFor="let mat of materials" value="{{}}">{{}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Which eventually has to be compiled to this:

```
  <select formControlName="material">
    <option value="mat_wood">Wood</option>
    <option value="mat_metal">Metal</option>
    <option value="mat_plastic">Plastic</option>
  </select>
```

Here we have a classical example of a custom select structure. The `<span class="select-value">` displays the selected option's text to the user. The `<select>` has `opacity` set to `0` and is positioned on top of the `<span>`, so when the user clicks, he clicks on it and activates it.

For each option I need to put the `mat_[something]` in the `value` attribute and the readable `Something` as text in the option, just like in the example above:
`<option value="mat_wood">Wood</option>`.

Question is: How can I put the selected option text inside the `<span>`? I'm looking for a reusable way of doing it.

---

**EDIT**:
Looking at the first answer shows (and I forgot to mention) that using a template variable does the job. But if we have an enclosing *ngFor loop that generates multiple selects, then we need to have dynamically generated template variables. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is you could refer to select as template variable say `mySelect`.

```
<select #mySelect formControlName="material">
  <option value="mat_wood">Wood</option>
  <option value="mat_metal">Metal</option>
  <option value="mat_plastic">Plastic</option>
</select>
```

And refer to its `options.text` property like this.
`{{ mySelect && mySelect.selectedIndex > -1 ? mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].text : ''}}` inside your span element.

You can read about template variables [here](https://itnext.io/working-with-angular-5-template-reference-variable-e5aa59fb9af)

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I've tried that method but it fails when your select is part of a *ngFor loop. I don't think there's a way of generating dynamic template variables in that case, is there?

Comment: Turns out it does work even in an ngFor loop. I've posted an answer with a link to an example. Thanks for making me try this approach again :) I guess I messed up the previous time.

Answer (score -2):

Try this example for dynamic option

**In Html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select"    [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let data of materials" [value]="getKey(data)">{{getValue(data)}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>You selected: {{selected}}</p>
```

**In TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-value-binding-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-value-binding-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-value-binding-example.css'],
})
export class SelectValueBindingExample {
  selected = 'option2';
  materials = [
  {"mat_wood": "Wood"},
  {"mat_metal": "Metal"},
  {"mat_plastic": "Plastic"}
]
getValue(obj)
{
return obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]
}
getKey(obj)
{
return Object.keys(obj)[0]
}
checkValue()
{
 console.log( this["mySelect"])
}
}
```

Comment: does this work in Angular 9?   I can't get the "getValue()" or "getKey()" methods to return the correct values.